# auto hot key, input for continuously holding shift while clicking instead of hitting both for every click

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to make all my apps have the same navigation keys as the app I use most (blender). I set up a script where when I shift middle click, it sends a middle click (middle click alone is reassigned to send left click). It works but the only problem is that I have to press shift every time I click, but I want to be able to just hold down shift and click many times to activate the AHK send.

here's the full script so far

```
#SingleInstance ignore 
#IfWinActive ahk_exe MagicaVoxel.exe
{ 
;Middle Mouse Button activates rotate 
MButton:: 
Send, {RButton down} 
KeyWait, MButton 
Send, {RButton up} 
Return 

;shift Middle Mouse Button activates pan
+MButton:: 
Send, {MButton down} 
KeyWait, MButton 
Send, {MButton up} 
Return 
}
```

Comment: The first key in a combination (in this case Shift) doesn't need to be released for repeating the combination-action, unleess you use `KeyWait, Shift`. Something else is wrong in your script. How do you assign MButton  to send left click?

Comment: edited the question to include the full script

Comment: Works perfectly on my system (Win10, Logitech Gaming Mouse G600)  in this program (MagicaVoxel-0.99.2-alpha-win64).